# Flutter router path not showing browser tab on navigating to another page while using generate route with cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

i am now doing a flutter project. and i use cubit for state management. for navigation i had made a file for routing.using generate route. i have given the router file code below. does anyone had an idea about this.i used block providers to give cubit and navigated to pages using named route.i works when we manually type the path in the browser tab and when we pressed back the url path is not refreshed.

```
class AppRouter {
  /* ADD REPOSITORY TO APP ROUTER */
  /* ADD REPOSITORY TO APP ROUTER */
  Repository repository;
  AppRouter() {
    repository = new Repository(apiService: ApiService());
  }

  Route generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "/":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: RouteSettings(name: '/'),
            builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
                  BlocProvider<HomeCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) {
                      return HomeCubit(repository: repository);
                    },
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<UserCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) {
                      return UserCubit(repository: repository);
                    },
                  )
                ],child:SplashScreen()
      case "/register":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
           settings: RouteSettings(name: '/REGISTER'),
            builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
                  BlocProvider<HomeCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) {
                      return HomeCubit(repository: repository);
                    },
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<SearchCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) =>
                        SearchCubit(repository: repository),
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<UserCubit>(
                    create: (BuildContext context) =>
                        UserCubit(repository: repository),
                  )
                ], child: RegisterScreen()));
      case '/signin':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
                create: (BuildContext context) =>
                    UserCubit(repository: repository),
                child: SigninScreen()),
                 settings: RouteSettings(name: '/signin'));            
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Error! No route Found...',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
          );
        });
    }
  }
}
```